# What if my travel date to arrive in the UK is after the initial month

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, legal

When applying for my visa I just wrote a random date for when I wanted to be in the UK (didn't have any set plans at that stage) I now hve my visa and see that I was given one month after the'intended' date I wrote down to enter the country. I cannot arrive until 3 days after that. What should I do???

Comment: Plan better next time ...

Comment: Not a big deal, read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90740/any-changes-to-uk-standard-visa-application-process/90786#90786